# Deserializing from Json to Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization

Here is my JSON file that is coming in from SWAGGER:

```
{
  "TrailerId": "33333",
  "UpdatedBy": "JWW",
  "Name": "REEFERERROR",
  "StatusDate": "2017-03-22T20:26:45.898Z",
  "Fuel": 23,
  "Location": {
    "Latitude": 522,
    "Longitude": -2350,
    "LocationDate": "2017-03-22T20:26:45.898Z"
  },
  "AmbientTemperature": 11,
  "Mode": {
    "Value": 2,
    "DisplayName": "Automatic"
  },
  "Power": {
    "Value": 0,
    "DisplayName": "Off"
  },
  "AlarmStatus": {
    "Value": 3,
    "DisplayName": "All"
  },
  "HasBatteryAlert": false,
  "HasFuelAlert": true,
  "HasPreventiveMaintenanceAlert": false,
  "SetPointTemperature": 23,
  "DischargeTemperature": 33,
  "ReturnTemperature": 22,
  "ServiceState": {
    "Value": 1,
    "DisplayName": "Remote"
  },
  "SwitchedOnHours": 22,
  "EngineHours": 345,
  "BatteryVoltage": 12,
  "Id": 0,
  "GuidId": "string"
}
```

JSON can deserialize it without a problem until it hits the "Mode" type.  The Mode type is defined as this:

```
 [DataContract]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeSafeEnumerationConverter))]
    public sealed class ReeferMode : TypeSafeEnumeration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        private ReeferMode(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }

        public static readonly ReeferMode Continuous = new ReeferMode(0, "Continuous");
        public static readonly ReeferMode StartStop = new ReeferMode(1, "Start/Stop");
        public static readonly ReeferMode Automatic = new ReeferMode(2, "Automatic");
        public static readonly ReeferMode None = new ReeferMode(-1, "None");
    }
```

When the file comes in to a class to convert from a TypeSafe Enumeration to Json values it uses this code:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader" /> to read from.</param>
        /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
        /// <param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param>
        /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
        /// <returns>The object value.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="JsonSerializationException"></exception>
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return null;

            var stringValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);

            var result = TypeSafeEnumeration.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(e => e.DisplayName.ToLower() == stringValue.ToLower() && IsSameOrSubclass(objectType, e.GetType()));

            if (result == null)
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Enumeration Name not found in enumeration. Type:{objectType} Value:{stringValue}");

            return result;
        }
```

The problem is the objectType always comes in a the "Mode" but no matter what I do, the value object is always null.  Because it is null, I can't set the value in the property mapping and it does not persist to the database.  The enumeration is found in the GetAll() method, it just can't to the .FirstOrDefault because the existingValue is null.

Any thoughts on how to deserialize a TypeSafeEnumeration with JSON to persist into a the Entity Framework mapping?

Thanks.

John

Comment: Can you share a prototype implementation for `TypeSafeEnumeration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we fixed the problem.

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName || reader.TokenType == Json.Token.Startobject)

{
   var tokenObject = JObject.Load(reader);
   stringValue = tokenObject["DisplayName"].Value<string();
}
```

we had to create a Json.linq.JObject, check the token for either StartObject (begin of read) or the PropertyName tag.  When we found them, then we load the reader into the object, locate the value and return it.  I was missing the Linq object to traverse the Json object.  Before we trying to use the existingValue passed in which was null.  So the serializer.Deserialize was failing because the string was null.